# Headache getting Polymer 3 app to work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, lit-element

I'm literally just trying to get a simple Polymer 3 app with lit-element to work.  From VS Code, I have run polymer serve, and when I navigate to localhost:8081 to my index.html, I get the error in F12 tools:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/lib/mixins/properties-mixin.js".Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

This is extremely frustrating and I've been trying to resolve this issue for quite a while.

In HTML, I am simply including the file as expected:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Polymer 3</title>
        <script type="module" src="./node_modules/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js"></script>        
        <script type="module" src="./MyApp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <my-app score='5'></my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in the JavaScript file for my custom element, I am doing the following:

```
import {LitElement, html} from './node_modules/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js';

class MyApp extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }//end ctor

    static get properties() {
        return {
            score: Number
        }
    }//end properties

    //no get template needed.  Use _render instead
    _render({score}) {
        return html`The score is ${score}`;  //equivalent {{score}} or [[score]]
    }//end _render    window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);  

    static get is() {
        return 'my-app';
    }//end is

}//end class

window.customElements.define(MyApp.is(), MyApp);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am very new to some of the Web component technology.  I've used HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, etc. for a long time, but this new push for Web components and Polymer 3 is like a very different animal, and I'm having trouble grasping some aspects of the workflow.

Comment: Node modules are automatically rewritten by `polymer serve` and `polymer build`. Also, I don't think `polymer serve` is really designed for use with `LitElement`. Maybe have a look at something like [`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server).

Comment: Just run `npm install` to get the dependencies

Comment: remove the lithtml import in your index.html. Then remove the ./node_modules/ of your import in your MyApp.html and you should be fine. Polymer serve works also just fine with lit.